# dojo - programmatic way to show invalid message

Tags: dojo

dojo newbie - giving it a shot.
After submitting a form, If an error is returned from the server I would like to show that message on the dijit.form.ValidationTextBox

```
var user_email = dijit.byId("login_user_email");
user_email.set("invalidMessage", data["result"]["user_email"]);
//need to force show the tooltip but how???
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

See it in action at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/HGBnq/).

1. Just show tooltip:

   ```
   var textBox = bijit.byId("validationTextBox");
   dijit.showTooltip(
       textBox.get("invalidMessage"), 
       textBox.domNode, 
       textBox.get("tooltipPosition"),
       !textBox.isLeftToRight()
   );
   ```
2. Temporarily switch textBox validator, force validation, restore the original validator:

   ```
   var originalValidator = textBox.validator;
   textBox.validator = function() {return false;}
   textBox.validate();  
   textBox.validator = originalValidator;
   ```

Or do both at once.

Comment: I like :)  Seems like there'd be more on this, I suppose they'd assume you'd just make your own widget...?

Comment: #2 worked for me thanks. Only modification I had to make is to set the focus on my text box as the first line:
`textBox.focus();`

Answer (score 3):

I think you can show the tooltip via myVTB.displayMessage('this is coming from back end validation'); method

Answer (score 2):

you need to do the validation in the validator-method. like here http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/form/ValidationTextBox-tricks
you also need to focus the widget to show up the message! dijit.byId("whatever").focus()

Comment: thanks: pity I can't show the tooltip without going through the validator method. I'm just trying to show the result of the server interaction via the tooltip for the ValidationTextBox

Answer (score 1):

@arber solution is the best when using the new dojo. Just remember to set the focus to the TextBox before calling the "displayMessage" method.
I am using dojo 1.10 which works create as follows:

```
function showCustomMessage(textBox, message){
    textBox.focus();
    textBox.set("state", "Error");
    textBox.displayMessage(message);
}
```

Dojo reference guid for ValidationTextBox: https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/ValidationTextBox.html

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is ancient, but hopefully this'll help someone. Yes, you should use validators, but if you have a reason not to, this will display the message and invalidate the field:

```
        function(textbox, state /*"Error", "Incomplete", ""*/, message) {
            textbox.focus();
            textbox.set("state", state);
            textbox.set("message", message);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call directly the "private" function:

`textBox._set('state', 'Error');`

You get the same result as @phusick suggested but with less code and arguably in a more direct and clean way.

Notes:
`_set` is available to `ValidationTextBox` as declared on its base class `dijit/_WidgetBase`.

Live demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/gibbok/kas7aopq/

```
dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
dojo.require("dijit.form.ValidationTextBox");
dojo.require("dijit.Tooltip");

dojo.ready(function() {

  var textBox = dijit.byId("validationTextBox");

  dojo.connect(dijit.byId("tooltipBtn"), "onClick", function() {

    dijit.showTooltip(
      textBox.get('invalidMessage'),
      textBox.domNode,
      textBox.get('tooltipPosition'), !textBox.isLeftToRight()
    );
  });

  dojo.connect(dijit.byId("validatorBtn"), "onClick", function() {
    // call the internal function which set the widget as in error state
    textBox._set('state', 'Error');
    /*
        code not necessary
        var originalValidator = textBox.validator;
        textBox.validator = function() {return false;}
        textBox.validate();  
        textBox.validator = originalValidator;
    */
  });

});
```